# Unable to Create Image of Special Characters

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, special-characters, httphandler, drawstring

I have written a imageHandler.ashx in c# which draw image of a text on a fly . Its takes a parameter string txt. The Handler is called from Asp.net page. At the time of calling, if text contains the character @ or  any special character .it Does not create the images of @,or any special character's  given to it.

According to my R&D the problem is with a Graphics.DrawString() method some how its is unable to write special characters.so please tell me how to create a image of a special characters
Code I am using :

```
  String signatureText =  HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(signatureText);
  System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection fontCollection = new System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection();

            FontFamily ff1 = fontCollection.Families[0];
            // Initialize graphics
            RectangleF rectF = new RectangleF(0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
   Bitmap pic = new Bitmap((int) rectF.Width,imgHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pic);
            //g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.Default;
           // g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
            g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;

         Font font1 = new Font(ff1, imgHeight, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
         float bestFontSize = BestFontSize(g, new Size(imgWidth, imgHeight), font1, signatureText);
         Font font2 = new Font(ff1, bestFontSize, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel); 

            // Set colors
            Color fontColor = Color.Black;
            Color rectColor = Color.White;
            SolidBrush fgBrush = new SolidBrush(fontColor);
            SolidBrush bgBrush = new SolidBrush(rectColor);

            // Rectangle or ellipse?
            g.FillRectangle(bgBrush, rectF);

           // Set font direction & alignment
            StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
            //format.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft;

            format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;


            // Finally, draw the font
            g.DrawString(signatureText, font2, fgBrush, rectF, format);
            pic = (Bitmap) ImageUtility.ResizeImageWithAspectRatio(pic, imgWidth, imgHeight, true);

            pic.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Any help is Appreciated Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DrawString() don't have any problem while writing special characters if they are provided in font file (.ttf)

Problem can be in the following line

```
System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection fontCollection = new System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection();
```

Specially with the font you get in ff1

```
FontFamily ff1 = fontCollection.Families[0];
```

In your case it means Font ff1 don't have representation for some or all special characters.

Since I don't know how many font files you are getting from fontCollection.Families, if fontCollection.Families contain more than one font file try next one.

```
FontFamily ff1 = fontCollection.Families[1]; // and so on.
```

Or try to add font file with all special characters (if System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection is absolutely necessary ).

Alternatively you can use InstalledFontCollection instead of PrivateFontCollection

```
System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection  fontCollection = new System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection();
```

Which will give you all installed fonts of the system on which application is running through its Families property [InstalledFontCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.installedfontcollection.aspx).

Easiest way is (if only one font is required, as you are using only one font in your provided code)
using constructor of FontFamily class with a string type parameter [FontFamily](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602323.aspx).

Consider replacing this line

```
FontFamily ff1 = fontCollection.Families[0];
```

With this one

```
FontFamily fontFamily1 = new FontFamily("Arial");
```

Arial must be installed on the system where application is running.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

DrawString doesn't have any problem with drawing special characters like @ or copyright (I just tested it and produced the image below).

[image]

The problem might be from your URL parameter. Try encoding your text using `Server.UrlEncode` when passing the text, and then `Server.UrlDecode` before giving it to DrawString.

Comment: no its not related to encoding or decoding i had directly given the text to g.drawstring for example: g.DrawString("@test", font2, fgBrush, rectF, format); but its doesnot display @ .